# map viewer widget: how to show information of a marker with the link of address on it?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I created models by NGSI-LD with the coordinates but i couldn't see any markers icon on the Map Viewer Widget.I only see the 2 markers of NGSI. How can i see the markers with the link googlemap on it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7crZv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JnGw.png)

I tried to add other location but it didn't work . I expect to display the marker and its information